# My tailwind CSS class isn't adding styles to my html

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, ckeditor

I want to change styles of an element, but when I use a class or id selector doesn't work. When I use something like `h1` without any class or id it works.

The following works:

```css
/* this works */
@layer base {
    h1 {
        font-size: revert !important;
    }
```

but this doesn't work

```css
/* doesn't work */
@layer base {
    .revert-tailwind h1 {
        font-size: revert !important;
    }
```

```
<ckeditor
    class="revert-tailwind"
    :editor="Editor"
    v-model="form.description"
    :config="editorConfig"
></ckeditor>
```